# React Native - Positioned absolute view is behind other components of the screen

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, absolute

guys.

So, I'm trying to make a simple Select Dropdown Menu with React Native. I've another code that works as well, but the problem is within the Position absolute. I've tried a lot of times but no success.

The problem:

The absolute View is behind others components of screen.

Expected behavior:

The absolute view above all components

Can someone help me?

This is my snack representation of this problem.

https://snack.expo.dev/@ellyssonmiike/shallow-croissant

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `react-native-portalize` library for this problem. Portalize basically renders the content of Portal in Host component.

Here is the snack with the Portalize implementation: https://snack.expo.dev/@truetiem/shallow-croissant

First you need to install `react-native-portalize`:

```sh
yarn add react-native-portalize
```

Then wrap your app with Host component:

```js
import {Host} from 'react-native-portalize';
```

```js
<Host>
  // your app content
</Host>
```

And wrap your dropdown list with Portal component:

```js
import {Portal} from 'react-native-portalize';
```

```js
<Portal>
  <View style={[styles.dropdownMenu, { top: height }]}>
    // your dropdown content
  </View>
</Portal>
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

you need just a little re-arrangement for your stylesheet as follows:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    zIndex: 10
  },
  dropdownContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    zIndex:10,
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    width: '100%',
    elevation: 10,
  },
  dropdownMenu: {
    flex:1
  }
});
```

You can also remove {{top: height}} for Item style. I don't see any need for it.